# i want to hide few columns in slickgrid on button click and show all the columns default when i refresh the page

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

is it possible to show and hide some Slickgrid Columns on button click and set the Columns to default when the particular Slickgrid page is refreshed. I am new to angularjs, it will be useful for me please post your comments.

Comment: i have tried to implement in custom..but it dint workout

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use ng-hide to that column. And make initial value of it to false. so that it will be visible initially. make it true on your event. Every time it comes to this view it will be visible then

Comment: thanks for your reply friend..is it possible to use ng-hide in slickgrid?

Answer (score 0):

// grid is my grid instance variable

//First Do

var mycolumns = grid.getColumns();

for (var i = 0; i < mycolumns.length; i++) {

//remove the columns you need here based on your logic

}

grid.setColumns(mycolumns );

// This is the proper way to hide columns in slickgrid and they will
//not be in the grid but still in the dataview so you can still reference there //values a .hide() or ng-hide will do nothing for you.